# Null Pointer exception when I click on VideoView

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I am using standout library, I added a videoView in it, Everything is running correctly, Except if i click on video then mediaController Is not Showing and i am getting null pointer exception.
Here is my code:-

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    
 getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple, frame, true);
    localVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(StandOutExampleActivity.getActivity());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(localVideoView);
    localVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    localVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
            + R.raw.ba);
    localVideoView.start();
```

Log File:-

```
    67: E/AndroidRuntime(1997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.View.onAttachedToWindow(View.java:11709)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12125)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2450)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1207)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    01-14 19:48:56.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post your log

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know what is null pointer exception but i added everything correct on videoview so why i am getting this exception?

Comment: Log File Added @MoubeenFarooqWarar

Comment: I am not expert, but are you sure what localVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
            + R.raw.ba); is correct path? This string looks suspicious

Comment: Ya That is one correct, My video is playing and i am changing video, But If i click on video then my app crashes. I dont know why

Comment: I traced code and i found that some problem in MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(StandOutExampleActivity.a); this line.

Comment: Have you added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your `AndroidManifest`? If not, trying to set the video path and save the video could cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, I added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> line to my manifest file

Comment: I all-ready told you that i am using standout library so if you are not familiar with that then i am telling you that i am using this code like in a service class, Not in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application loads and plays the video fine but crashes when you click on the screen, the most likely reason is that your `VideoView` does not know how to handle touch events. Try adding the following to your code:

```
localVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // Execute action on touch event
        return true;
    }
});
```

The code snippet above sets up a listener for touch events so that they do not go unhandled.

Comment: Ya, Thanks. I am also doing same, And creating my own seek bar with play and pause button.